# Bind view listener to Controller in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

My question is very basic but somehow I am not able to figure out a solution to it. 
I have a view, Its xtype is gridPanel. It's id is 'mainGrid'. 
On its listener method, I have a 'itemdblclick' registered. Now I want to move this 'itemdblclick' inside a controller. 
I did this but it is not working.

```
Ext.define('PfalzkomApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


     init: function() {
        this.control({

            '#mainGrid': {
                  itemdblclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

                   // My logic is here
                }
             }
    });
     }

});
```

Also how I link my view to this controller? I know how to do it in Extjs 5 but not in ExtJs4.2.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `id`, i.e grid `id`. And, also put `itemId` as same as `id`.

```
Ext.define('PfalzkomApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    view:[''], //your view

    onMainGridItemDbClick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        alert('this is alert');  
     },  
     init: function() {
        this.control({

            '#mainGrid': {
                  itemdblclick: this.onMainGridItemDbClick
             }
       });
     }

});
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. Another thing I was missing was that I forgot to add this controller in Application.js. After doing that this code works.